# RavenDB export\import data to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ravendb

Simple question: How to export data from SQL Server to RavenDB?

I wrote script which takes data from SQL Server and stores in raven but it works very slow. About 2500 inserts per second.

EDIT:
My code

```
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i+=8196)
    {
        StoreInTaven(WordStats.Skip(i).Take(8196).Select(x => new KeyPhraseInfo(){
           Key = x.Word,
           Id = x.Id,
           Count = x.Count,
           Date = x.Date
        }));
        GC.Collect();
    }



public static void StoreInTaven(IEnumerable<KeyPhraseInfo> wordStats)
{
     using(var session = store.OpenSession())
     {
           foreach (var wordStat in wordStats)
           {
              session.Store(wordStat);
           }

           session.SaveChanges();
     }
}
```

Comment: Post the code you're using to insert to RavenDB. The speed of insertion is a factor of your code, and possibly the machine it's running on.

Answer (score 1):

I was just doing the same thing. Speed is not really a concern for me so I don't know if this is any faster than yours.

```
public static void CopyFromSqlServerToRaven(IDocumentSession db, bool ravenDeleteAll=true)
{
    if (ravenDeleteAll) db.DeleteAll();

    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(SqlConnectionString))
    {
        var command = new SqlCommand(SqlGetContentItems, connection);
        command.Connection.Open();
        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                db.Store(new ContentItem
                            {
                                    Id = reader["Id"].ToString(),
                                    Title = (string)reader["Name"],
                                    Description = (string)reader["ShortDescription"],
                                    Keywords = (string)reader["SearchKeywords"]
                            });
            }
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am doing something like you but for 100 billion rows it takes a long time.

Answer (score 0):

I believe its supported for 1,000 writes per second on standard server.

When I increased my cache size the performance increased.
Raven/Esent/CacheSizeMax

http://ravendb.net/docs/server/administration/configuration